# Optimize nested loop over a fixed object with itertools.product

Tags: python, nested-loops, python-itertools

I have a fixed object, like so:

```
TAG_SET = [...]
```

I iterate over it twice in a loop

```
for x in very_outer_object:
    # ...
    for t1, t2 in itertools.product(TAG_SET, repeat=2)
```

Is it possible to create one product that is reused? The result of `itertools.product` is not immutable. It's a generator of some sort (i.e. it uses `yield` in its implementation).

This loop is the performance bottleneck in my program so I'm looking to optimize it.

Comment: is there a way to loop less? Maybe through combinations instead of product?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `list` on the generator object forces it to evaluate all its items:

```
products = list(itertools.product(TAG_SET, repeat=2))

for x in very_outer_object:
    # ...
    for t1, t2 in products:
    # ...
```

`products` can now be reused in your inner loop.

Provided `len(TAG_SET)` isn't extremely large this should not present any memory problems.